# Monitoring decimal values on Perfmon using User Settables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I am currently using sp_user_counter1 to store database information on Perfmon, which can be recovered by AWS CloudWatch, but the values are Decimal, and the sp_user_counter1 parameter supplied must be an int.

So when I give the stored procedure a value of 12.34567 it report 12.00000 to the perfmon counter....

The sp code is:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sys.sp_user_counter1 @newvalue INT AS
    DBCC setinstance ('SQLServer:User Settable', 'Query', 'User counter 1', @newvalue)
```

Can I just call `DBCC setinstance` and give it the decimal value???
I never tried this because I didnt found anyone doing this, I dont know the consequences....

Can this be done?? Is this secure??

Here is the User Setabble documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187480.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.set_user_counter1 
(
    @newvalue DECIMAL(18,2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBCC setinstance (
        'SQLServer:User Settable'
        , 'Query'
        , 'User counter 1'
        , @newvalue
    );
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.set_user_counter1 12.5
```

results in:

> Msg 2560, Level 16, State 9, Procedure set_user_counter1, Line 7
>   Parameter 4 is incorrect for this DBCC statement.

Running the following shows you the "help" entry for the `DBCC setinstance`:

```
DBCC TRACEON (2588); /* show DBCC Help */
DBCC TRACEON (2520); /* show undocumented command help */
DBCC HELP ('setinstance')
```

This returns:

> dbcc setinstance (objectname, countername, instancename, value)
>
> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Unfortunately, that is no help determining if `value` can only be an int.

In fact, the [MSDN page you linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187480.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) states the following:

> A counter can monitor any single integer value

Comment: Oh perfect, I think I will do the bad way, multiplying by 1000 and then dividing by 1000 when retrieving the counter...